# Creating new row if we mutiple values for key/ Lists

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have been working on list Here is the list which is been created . And i have a dictionary created for the list.
Was in need of creating Multiple rows from that list value matching with dictionary.

List :

```
['F104', 'F5334','F105','F5332','F1212','F1242B','F1242','F1015','F1015B','F1000']
```

My dictionary:

```
  dict =   {​​​​​'F105': ['F1212', 'F5332'],
  'F104': ['F105', 'F5334'],
  'F1212': ['F1000', 'F1242B'],
  'F1242B': ['F1015B'],
  'F1242': ['F1015B', 'F1015']}
```

Expected Output(Data Frame):

```
F104    F5334   null    null    null
F104    F105    F1212   F1000   null
F104    F105    F1212   F1242B  F1015B
F104    F105    F5332   null    null​​​​​
```

Can someone help please.
Thanks in advance

Elaborate explanation:
iteration 1:
List value is "F104"
From Dict we have 2 value
Create 2 rows.
Data Frame:

```
F104 F5534
F104 F105
```

iteration 2:
List value is "F5534"
From Dict we has 0 value
Keep Data frame unchanged
Data Frame:

```
F104 F5534
F104 F105
```

iteration 3:
List value is "F105"
From Dict we have 2 value
Create 1 rows add value to existing row.
Data Frame:

```
F104 F5534
F104 F105 F1212
F104 F105 F5332
```

iteration 4:
List value is "F5332"
From Dict we has 0 value
Keep Data frame unchanged
Data Frame:

```
F104 F5534
F104 F105 F1212
F104 F105 F5332
```

iteration 5:
List value is "F1212"
From Dict we has 2 value
Create 1 rows add value to existing row.
Data Frame:

```
F104 F5534
F104 F105 F1212 F1000
F104 F105 F1212 F1242B
F104 F105 F5332
```

So on......

Comment: Can you explain clearly how the data frame is related to the list and the dictionary ? What are the df columns, what are the rows ?

Comment: @hpchavaz, Hi, I want to create the Dataframe from list and Dictionary, Columns can be any thing like level1....leveln.Here F104 has 2 values in Dictionary . we have to create 2 rows . Later the F105 has 2 diffrent values we have to create 2 row as shown above. so on

Comment: Why does `F104` appears 4 times in dataframe?

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh, If you look at the list My intial value is F104, So rest all are its child with additional chlds. If there are more than 1 it created new row with keeping pervious data.

Comment: @RahulK You commented "Here F104 has 2 values in Dictionary" but in the dictionary F104 as one value which is a list of FOUR items in which  both 'F105' and  'F5334' appear twice. What are the semantics of the list and the dictionary ?

Comment: @hpchavaz, Here i have list as my input value. and Dictionary as my reference value for creating Data frame. If you look at List and dictionary my first value is F104 . But from dictionary. we have 2 unique associated for F104 i.e "F105" and "F5332". Here we create 2 rows for my first iteration. Now "F105" has 2 unique values as well but "F5332" does not have any value associate with it. so first row remains same. But F105 creates 2 row with F104, F105 with its associate vales i.e F1212 and F1000.The loop goes on ...

Comment: @hpchavaz, I have added iterations to question . Can please check and help me out with this?

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh,  I have added iterations to question . Can please check and help me out with this?